# Not Too Happy with the Android Action Bar... How Can I Reduce Its Size

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I don't really like the new Action Bar Android has come up with -- and apparently forced me to use in later API levels.  But, since it appears I'm stuck with it -- I have no more Menu Button and I need the functionality I've lost, I'd like to minimize the annoyance factor.

Can anybody tell me how NOT to display the Icon/Logo?  It's easy enough to suppress the Title, but the logo is still too much -- and provides zero helpfulness.

Also, can anybody tell me how to reduce the height of the bar?  Currently, it's about about 1/4" (about half a centimeter for you metric types), but that's easily twice as large as it needs to be -- especially if I can ditch the graphics.

Finally, there's a big empty black space between the left side of my screen and the first menu item.  This wouldn't bother if my five menu items fit on the display, but naturally they don't.  Does anybody know how to encourage my software to push the menu items a tad to the left so they fit??

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean)) to get rid of the button.

As for the height of the Action Bar, I don't believe it can be changed without setting up a new theme. In Android's `Theme.Holo`, it has an attribute [`<item name="actionBarSize">56.0dip</item>`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarSize). You *should* be able to change this if you extend that theme into your own. (Keep in mind that this may denigrate the UX since people are expecting it to be of a certain size.)

As for your last question, I believe icon spacing is fixed. Can you show exactly what you mean by "a big empty black space"? They should be evenly distributed across the bar.

Comment: Once I changed my menu items' showAsAction setting from "ifRoom" to "always", the left-most menu item moved to the left to make room, so I suppose that's not too bad, but I'll try your suggestion and see how that works.  Thanks.  Just did, works great!!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you simply hide the action bar and provide your own menu in your activity layout? Seems to me that you want to fit a square in a disc ...

Just use the ActionBar for what it is meant to be used. If you don't like it, hide it and make your own control.

I mean, no title, no left side icon, ... Then what's the point of using it?

Comment: Agreed. Using the action bar, but then changing it so it looks/works different than every other action bar, doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't want to hide the action bar and then provide a menu (button?) because my screen is already pretty cluttered and I don't want to code up something that already exists in the OS.  I don't want to display the icon or title because they don't provide any added functionality to my application.  And I don't agree that hiding a particular detail of a particular widget makes it "work different than every other action bar" -- the menu certainly isn't different, I'm just trying to display it more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You actually *can* remove the action bar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Yes I know.  I don't want to hide the bar, just part of it.

Comment: The question is to reduce the size of the actionbar and not remove it